# DBeaver and Azure SQL Data Warehouse - SQL Error [104455] [S0001]: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases

Tags: azure-synapse, dbeaver

I have a series of Azure SQL Data Warehouse databases on differing logical servers.  I primarily use DBeaver to interact with them (as we are working to get the ADW-capable version of Management Studio deployed).

I have JDBC connections configured from DBeaver for all the various databases but uniquely on one database's connection, when attempting in DBeaver to navigate the object tree, the following error occurs when expanding the tables, views, indexes, and procedures to show the list of said objects:

```
SQL Error [104455] [S0001]: USE statement is not supported to switch between
databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different     
Database.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: USE statement is   
not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to 
connect to a different Database.
```

The various ADW databases and servers were provisioned within weeks of each other by our local Azure enablement team (including MSFT staff).  I personally created the logins/users on the databases using the same T-sql.

Why would the behavior be different on these PaaS databases?

Answer (score 3):

The SQL **s**erver in Azure is a logical container, not the same physical container as the server (aka instance) in the box version of SQL **S**erver. That introduces a number of differences including the inability to support "USE" as it is currently implemented. More details on this is documented on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information

When you connect to Azure SQL DB or SQL DW, SSMS first connects to master to get the list of databases (and some other stuff). When you navigate the Object Browser in SSMS to look at various objects in different DBs/DWs/StretchDBs, it will open a new connection for each database you browse.

From your description, it looks like the version of DBeaver you used is operating under the assumption it is connected to the local SQL Server hence the "USE" failure. Suggest you ping them to see if they plan to address this in some future update. You can also add your vote and comments to the Azure SQL DB feedback page https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/14822082-allow-the-use-statement-to-switch-between-database

Comment: In this case, the tool works for many ADW databases without complaints about USE, but one specific DB complains.

Comment: Is it the same version of the tool? Both SQL DB and SQL DW do not support the USE statement so it will fail if the tool uses that command when navigating between DBs/DWs. I'm not familiar with DBeaver so I don't know how it's handling the browse experience.

Comment: Yes, DBeaver running on one PC with connections setup to many ADW databases on a few logical servers.